# What is wrong with my bidirectional infinite scrolling in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I built an infinite scroll for a mobile web app built with AngularJS with the following extras features:

1. I built it to be bidirectional
2. This is for a mobile web app so I wanted it to unload out-of-view contents to avoid memory issues

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D5fT3/3/) link.

Now, I have a few questions and I also needs a small code review:

1. I am not familiar with promises, but `then()` seems to be executed before `$digest`. Thus, I need to delay my codes with `$timeout`. For me, it's a sign that something is wrong. I would like to remove the `$timeout` on lines 85 and 98. The `$timeout` on line 85 is a bit "hacky", I need to make sure it is executed ms after `then()` otherwise, it won't work and I don't know why.
2. I would like to know if it's considered a "good practice" to call a `$scope` method from a directive. In my code, I am calling `$scope.init(value)` from my directive.
3. Including jQuery for a `position()` is quite funny. Should I be using a services with a function that does what `$.position()` does?

I know those could be seperate questions but they are really related to my piece of code.

For those who do not want to click on the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D5fT3/3/) link, here is the code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="fixed" scroll-watch="4" scroll-up="loadTop()" scroll-down="loadBottom()">
    <ul>
        <li data-id="{{i.id}}" ng-repeat="i in items" ng-class="calculateType(i.id)">{{i.id}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
function Main($scope, $timeout, $q) {
    var cleanup = 5;

    $scope.items = [];

    //This is called from the scrollWatch directive. IMO, this shouldn't be a good idea
    $scope.init = function(value) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        //This $timeout is used to simulate an Ajax call so I will keep it there
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.items = [{id: +value}];

            $scope.loadTop();
            $scope.loadBottom();

            deferred.resolve();
        }, 200);

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    //This is only used to simulate different content's heights
    $scope.calculateType = function(type) {
        return 'type-' + Math.abs(type) % 4;  
    };

    $scope.loadBottom = function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer(),
            counter;

        if ($scope.items.length > 1) {
            $scope.items.splice(0, cleanup);
        }

        //This $timeout is used to simulate an Ajax call so I will keep it there
        $timeout(function() {
            counter = (($scope.items[$scope.items.length - 1]) || {id: 0}).id;

            for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
                $scope.items.push({id: counter + i});
            }

            deferred.resolve();
        }, 200);

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    $scope.loadTop = function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer(),
            counter;

        //Why can't I use this here?
        //$scope.items.splice($scope.items.length-cleanup, $scope.items.length);

        //This $timeout is used to simulate an Ajax call so I will keep it there
        $timeout(function() {
            counter = (($scope.items[0]) || {id: 0}).id;

            for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
                $scope.items.unshift({id: counter - i});
            }

            deferred.resolve();
        }, 200);

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    //Why is this method needs to be delayed inside the directive? I would like to call it in loadTop()
    $scope.removeBottom = function() {
        $scope.items.splice($scope.items.length-cleanup, $scope.items.length);
    };
}

angular.module('scroll', []).directive('scrollWatch', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    var lastScrollTop = 0;

    return function($scope, elm, attr) {
        var raw = elm[0];

        $scope.init(attr.scrollWatch).then(function() {
            //Why do I need this? It looks like the resolve is called before the $digest cycle
            $timeout(function() {
                raw.scrollTop = $('li[data-id="' + attr.scrollWatch + '"]').position().top;
            }, 300); //This value needs to be great enough so it is executed after the $scope.loadTop()'s resolve, for now, I know that I can set it to 300 but in real life app?
        });

        elm.bind('scroll', function() {
            if (raw.scrollTop > lastScrollTop && raw.scrollTop + raw.offsetHeight >= raw.scrollHeight) {
                $scope.$apply(attr.scrollDown);
            } else if (raw.scrollTop < lastScrollTop && raw.scrollTop === 0) {
                var scrollHeight = raw.scrollHeight;

                $scope.$apply(attr.scrollUp).then(function() {
                    //Why do I need this? It looks like the resolve is called before the $digest cycle
                    $timeout(function() {
                        raw.scrollTop = raw.scrollHeight - scrollHeight;

                        //I would like to move this in the $scope.loadTop()
                        $scope.removeBottom();
                    });
                });
            }

            lastScrollTop = raw.scrollTop;
        });
    };
}]);
```

Thank you

Comment: Just call $scope.$digest yourself before you resolve the promise: http://jsfiddle.net/D5fT3/6/. I think $timeout calls $digest after the execution of the callback.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o84ryzNp36Q
Is a great video on Promises, how to write them and how they work.

https://github.com/stackfull/angular-virtual-scroll
Is a directive replacement for ng-repeat that doesn't load anything not on screen It does from what I can tell exactly what your looking for.

I would have put this as a comment but you need 50 cred or reputation or whatever they call it.